# Is there any way to change the port used by RemoteConnect?

Tags: remote-access, networking

It looks like the new `RemoteConnect` and `RemoteRunProcess` functions have the potential to dramatically simplify one of my workflows.

However, I will probably need to SSH to machines that have *non-default SSH ports*( the default port is 22) open.

Is there any way to change this, maybe on the SSH side? Nothing obvious jumps out at me from the documentation.

Comment: This works for mail servers running on non-standard ports `MailServerConnect["host.example.com", Authentication -> <|"PortNumber" -> NNN|>]`. Try that with `RemoteConnect`.

Comment: Sadly that does not appear to work. Looking at the def for `RemoteConnect` (it's not `ReadProtected` or anything) there really isn't a way to do it.

Comment: You may want to do the [port tunneling](https://www.tecmint.com/create-ssh-tunneling-port-forwarding-in-linux/). However, this is not a MA solution.

Comment: Do you have a solution now?I'm struggling with that, too

Answer (score 2):

With the current implementation of `RemoteConnect`, it seems that this is unfortunately not possible. Port 22 is hardcoded in the Wolfram Library that is used for SSH connections.

Apart from an elegant and simple solution with port tunneling, mentioned by @yarchik in the comments, you can also use a somehow more clumsy workaround with using an external library. I've used a python library [paramiko](https://www.paramiko.org/) in the code below.

```
session = StartExternalSession["Python"]

ExternalEvaluate[session, "
   import paramiko

   client = paramiko.SSHClient()
   client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
   client.connect('localhost', port=5000, username='domen', password='***')

   _stdin, _stdout,_stderr = client.exec_command(\"whoami\")
   _stdout.read().decode()"]
(* laptop\domen *)
```